# Winter Bash 2021!

Tags: discussion, fun, winter-bash

[Continuing the tradition](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Winterbash):

Winter Bash started today and will run into the new year.

Useful links:

- [Official site](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com)
- [Travel leaderboard](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/travel.stackexchange.com)
- [Unofficial hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373000)

Final standings:

1. Mark Mayo (12 hats)
2. Xnero (11 hats)
3. jcaron (8 hats)
   Willeke (8 hats)